# Image randomizer function inside <td> on button click

Tags: javascript

Hello I am very new to coding, I did try to lookup for an answer on stackoverflow and other forums but can't seem to put it all together. *This is a self project for school*, they're asking me to build a `html+css` page and I'm trying to add script on my own since its not required.

So I have made a function called `getRandomImage` that shuffles through images, I want that function to be used when clicking my button so that the images showing inside the td gets randomized.

Sorry if it seems pretty basic, like i said i am completely new to this, thanks in advance

```js
function getRandomImage() {
  var myImages = new Array(3);
  myImages[0] = "../img/yandee0.jpg";
  myImages[1] = "../img/yandee1.jpg";
  myImages[2] = "../img/yandee2.jpg";

  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages.length);
  document.getElementById("MonImage").src = myImages[randomNum];
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: First, javascript code should be between <script /> tags, inside a <td /> tag is just text. Then, `getElementById("button")...`  doesn't work, it should be `document.getElementById("button")...`. You need to learn web basis, HTML and Javascript.

Comment: So it cannot be done?i cant use the function to change a value inside a td right? and yes i need to learn that's what im doing to try to learn, i been using sololearn to learn basics and practice a bit but i dont have a personal teacher to coach me

Comment: Yes, you can do it, just learn where to put every piece of code to make it work.

Comment: Furthermore `getRandomImage` returns a number, maybe it should return `images[rnd]`
Plus you miss the code to set the image in a cell

Comment: ok thanks ill work around this a bit more

Comment: @Triby k (i tried to shorten the code up there its updated) i think i have the function and vars ok now  but im having issues with the button and td not knowing wich to call where can i get a little hint please? :D

Comment: <td ><img id="MonImage"> </td>  added this and now i can see a picture logo but not the actual image! i am getting there!!! lol jpg and png, got it now wooot thank you.

Comment: @Yan, congratulations, nice job!